# What Are Some Good Tools for Learning Chess Openings?

Tags: opening, training, study

I have an online rating of 1900, and about 30% of my lost games have been lost because I clearly messed up in the opening, so I want to focus on my openings to improve my rating further.

I am looking for any specialized tools that would help me study and learn openings (preferably free ones). I know about Chessable, but I'm not a big fan of that website, because I don't particularly like the way MoveTrainer works (I find it boringly repetitive), and the courses are rather expensive. I'm looking for a tool that is more compact/simpler, that is specifically made to learn openings. I love Lichess studies, but there are only a limited amount of community studies available, and most of them don't go too much into details.

Are there any websites/programs you would recommend that would help me learn openings? Are there any specialized tools available for this task, or should I simply get into Chessbase and make my own studies/databases with it? I should note that I am aiming for an online rating of 2200.

Comment: "I have an online rating of 1900" - at what time control? Bullet, blitz, rapid, classical?

Comment: @IanBush blitz, but how relevant is that?

Comment: Focus on a repertoire of your own. Chessmood has good quality courses. They even gave free access to all courses a couple of times

Comment: Btw creating your own chessbase files is the way to go. Now the same thing can be done by creating your own lichess studies as well.

Comment: I suggest chesstempo. It features an opening training tool( based on your PGNs tho, you'll have to work on it). I actually use it to store my repertoire.

Comment: @Mephisto for blitz the Chessable courses work great. They focus on memorizing the moves, which is what you need to focus on in blitz, since you don't have time to puzzle out the whole position.

Comment: chess tempo is cool, but it focuses to heavily on memorization and not as much on ideas imo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chess.com and liChess have extensive opening libraries which you can use for study, but if you're looking for more detailed explanations of the ideas in the openings and not just moves, you should look to opening books. The FCO (Fundamental Chess Openings) book is a good one for a more shallow look at the openings, but if you want to go in depth on a particular opening there are individual books specific to nearly every opening. Beyond this, the youtube channel "hanging pawns" has a lot of higher level opening videos.